# Performance tuning of SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server, performance, stored-procedures

I am getting some errors like:

> Msg 205, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SearchUserswithLevels, Line 29
>   All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

I am attaching my  tables and also the stored procedure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users]
(
    [Login_ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Login_Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Login_Password] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [bigint] NULL,
    [ModifiedBy] [bigint] NULL,
    [Referal_ID] [bigint] NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [User_Address] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Phone] [nvarchar](14) NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [BankName] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [AccountName] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [IFSC] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [AccountNo] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [DOB] [datetime] NULL,
    [Created_Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [Modified_Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [Last_Login_Date_Time] [datetime] NULL,
    [UnsuscribeEmail] [int] NULL,
    [UnsuscribeSms] [int] NULL,
    [IsBanned] [int] NULL,
    [ISDeleted] [int] NULL,
    [Roles] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [IDPROF] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [IDPROFNO] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [PANCARDNO] [nvarchar](250) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

My stored procedure is like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SearchUserswithLevels 
     (@SearchParameter NVARCHAR(250),
      @Referal_ID BIGINT = NULL)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CURRENTDATE AS DATETIME = GETDATE()

    CREATE TABLE #temptable 
    (
        ID BIGINT,
        Login_Name NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
        NAME NVARCHAR(250) NULL,
        Levels INT,
        Referal_ID BIGINT NULL,
        User_Address NVARCHAR(max) NULL,
        Phone NVARCHAR(14) NULL,
        Email NVARCHAR(250) NULL,
        BankName NVARCHAR(250) NULL,
        AccountName NVARCHAR(250) NULL,
        IFSC NVARCHAR(250) NULL,
        AccountNo NVARCHAR(250) NULL,
        DOB DATETIME NULL,
        IDPROF NVARCHAR(250) NULL,
        IDPROFNO NVARCHAR(250) NULL,
        PANCARDNO NVARCHAR(250) NULL
    )

    ;WITH Hierarchy (
        Login_ID,
        Login_Name,
        NAME,
        Levels,
        Referal_ID,
        User_Address,
        Phone,
        Email,
        BankName,
        AccountName,
        IFSC,
        AccountNo,
        DOB,
        IDPROF,
        IDPROFNO,
        PANCARDNO
    ) AS 
    (
        SELECT 
            Login_ID,
            Login_Name,
            NAME,
            0,
            Referal_ID,
            User_Address,
            Phone,
            Email,
            BankName,
            AccountName,
            IFSC,
            AccountNo,
            DOB,
            IDPROF,
            IDPROFNO,
            PANCARDNO
        FROM 
            Users AS FirtGeneration
        WHERE 
            Referal_ID = @Referal_ID

        UNION ALL

        SELECT 
            NextGeneration.Login_ID,
            NextGeneration.Login_Name,
            NextGeneration.NAME,
            Parent.Levels + 1,
            Parent.Login_ID
            User_Address,
            NextGeneration.Phone,
            NextGeneration.Email,
            NextGeneration.BankName,
            NextGeneration.AccountName,
            NextGeneration.IFSC,
            NextGeneration.AccountNo,
            NextGeneration.DOB,
            NextGeneration.IDPROF,
            NextGeneration.IDPROFNO,
            NextGeneration.PANCARDNO
        FROM
            Users AS NextGeneration
        INNER JOIN 
            Hierarchy AS Parent ON NextGeneration.Referal_ID = Parent.Login_ID
    )
    INSERT INTO #temptable
        SELECT 
            Login_ID, Login_Name, NAME,
            (Levels + 1) AS Levels,
            Referal_ID,
            User_Address,
            Phone, Email, BankName, AccountName,
            IFSC, AccountNo, DOB, IDPROF, IDPROFNO,
            PANCARDNO   
        FROM 
            Hierarchy
        --WHERE Levels = @Levels
        ORDER BY 
            Login_ID
        OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767)

    SELECT 
        TP.ID, TP.Login_Name, TP.NAME,
        TP.Levels, TP.Referal_ID, TP.User_Address,
        TP.Phone, TP.Email, TP.BankName, TP.AccountName, TP.IFSC,
        TP.AccountNo, TP.DOB, TP.IDPROF, TP.IDPROFNO
    FROM 
        #temptable as TP
    WHERE 
        (TP.Email LIKE '%' + @SearchParameter + '%')
        OR (TP.Phone LIKE '%' + @SearchParameter + '%')
        OR (TP.NAME LIKE '%' + @SearchParameter + '%')
        OR (TP.ID LIKE '%' + @SearchParameter + '%')
END
```

Comment: Your question title is about performance, and you tagged performance as well. If you get an error, performance is not the question!

Comment: Yes, downvoted the question. Misleading title and typo error easy-peasy to find. This is trash question.

Answer (score 5):

After `UNION ALL` there is this:

```
Parent.Login_ID
User_Address,
```

which is interpreted by Sql Server as

```
Parent.Login_ID AS User_Address,
```

That makes it 1 field, not 2 as you probably intended. Add a comma and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `TP.PANCARDNO` in table `#temptable`

```
 INSERT INTO #temptable
    SELECT Login_ID,
        Login_Name,
        NAME,
        (Levels + 1) AS Levels,
        Referal_ID,
        User_Address,
        Phone,
        Email,
        BankName,
        AccountName,
        IFSC,
        AccountNo,
        DOB,
        IDPROF,
        IDPROFNO,
        PANCARDNO   FROM Hierarchy
    --WHERE Levels = @Levels
    ORDER BY Login_ID
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767)

    SELECT TP.ID,
        TP.Login_Name,
        TP.NAME,
        TP.Levels,
        TP.Referal_ID,
        TP.User_Address,
        TP.Phone,
        TP.Email,
        TP.BankName,
        TP.AccountName,
        TP.IFSC,
        TP.AccountNo,
        TP.DOB,
        TP.IDPROF,
        TP.IDPROFNO,
        TP.PANCARDNO
    FROM #temptable as TP
```